# Binding and Markup extension designer constructor error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When using custom binding or markup extensions I get the following error:

The type "BindingExtension" does not include a constructor that has the specified number of arguments.

AND

The type "MarkupExtension" does not include a constructor that has the specified number of arguments.

```
public class BindingExtension : Binding
{
    public BindingExtension()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public BindingExtension(string path) : base(path)
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        this.Source = WpfApplication1.Properties.Settings.Default;
        this.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
    }
}
```

[image: Error Picture]

I am using Visual Studio 2015 without extensions. It works as it should with 2013. I have tried completely removing VS2015 with revo uninstaller and I am still getting the error.

I am unable to replicate the error on my other computer. I feel like something needs to be deleted and reinstalled/created but I'm out of ideas. I have also tried clearing the component cache.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a setting that got changed. Tools > Options > XAML Designer > "Run project code in XAML Designer". What was unchecked. Uninstalling visual studio did not solve this issue because the settings are not deleted upon uninstall.

Comment: Just to add, I needed to clear my component cache, in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\<version>\ComponentModelCache`

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an option in VS2019? I couldn't see it.